# Remmina Remote Desktop Client - Unable to connect to RDP server

Tags: remote-desktop, centos, centos-7, remmina

I'm experiencing a some issues using [Remmina - The GTK+ Remote Desktop Client](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) / [FreeRDP/Remmina](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina); such as this: [I have to click on "Resize the window to fit remote resolution" to see my RDP session](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/issues/387)) and it's most likely due to I'm using outdated version.

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ rpm -q remmina remmina-plugins-rdp
remmina-1.0.0-8.el7.nux.x86_64
remmina-plugins-rdp-1.0.0-8.el7.nux.x86_64
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

while latest version is `1.1.2`, don't let `1.0.0` version fool you, as in reality (`Help`->`About` shows `0.9.99.1`) and other then using [Nux!](http://nux.ro/)'s outdated version I cannot get newer version to run on my `CentOS7`.

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) 
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ uname -a
Linux wcmisdlin02.uftmasterad.org 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 13 10:06:09 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

I also posted new topic: [CentOS • View topic - Remote Desktop Viewer](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=49301).

Did anyone else was able to get Remmina going somehow? What is other alternatives? I've tried [Pac](http://pastebin.com/f9zMXzDL) (also without luck).